# TypeError: Expected sequence or array-like, got <class 'keras.src.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm doing image classification and coded a model using transfer learning. Now I need to perform a K-Fold analysis on it but I get above error.

See the code for k-Fold below

````
log_list=[]
np.random.seed(2016)
kf = KFold(5,shuffle=True)

for train, test in kf.split(x):
    model = train_model()        
    foldn += 1
    
    print('number {} fold of {} folds cross validation'.format(foldn, n_splits))
    print('Split into training and validation set', len(X_train[train]), len(X_train[test]))   
        
    weights_path = os.path.join('cache', 'weights_' + str(foldn) + '.h5')
    
    callbacks = [                
                EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=0),
                ModelCheckpoint(weights_path, monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, verbose=1, mode='auto'),                
                ]
    log=model.fit(X_train[train], y_train[train], batch_size=32, epochs=40,
                  shuffle=True, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_train[test],y_train[test]),
                  callbacks=callbacks)
          
    plt.plot(log.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(log.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('model loss')
    plt.ylabel('model loss')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train','test','val_train','val_test'], loc='upper right')
    plt.show()
    
    plt.plot(log.history['acc'])
    plt.plot(log.history['val_acc'])
    plt.title('model acc')
    plt.ylabel('model acc')
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(['train','test'], loc='upper right')
    plt.show()```
````